# Does a parent element with "display: none" cause child imgs to not load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Currently, I'm using canvases to dynamically generate grayscale images with javascript.
The grayscale code is as follows:

```
// Grayscale w canvas method
function grayscale(src)
{
    var canvasUrl = false;

    try
    {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = src;
        canvas.width = imgObj.width;
        canvas.height = imgObj.height;
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        canvasUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        canvasUrl = false;
    }

    return canvasUrl;
}
```

In my code, my images are placed in a `div`.  The `div` has the setting "display:none" until the javascript executes and finishes generating grayscale representations of all the images, at which point it sets the `div` to have "display: block".

This works most of the time but not **all** of the time.  *Occasionally*, the `div` will not show up, because an error occurs on the following line:

```
var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

[image: error]

Based on related questions here on SO, the general solution seems to be to use `$(window).load(func);` to run the grayscale generation code.

However, that *is* what I am doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var animateTime = 250;

    // On window load. This waits until images have loaded which is essential
    $(window).load(function(){
        // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
        $(".item img").animate({opacity:1},animateTime);

        // clone image
        $('.item img').each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
                var el = $(this);
                el.parent().css({"width":el.css("width"),"height":el.css("height")});
                el.dequeue();
            });
            this.src = grayscale(this.src);

            if(!this.src)
                alert('An error occurred.'); // handle the occasional DOM error...
        });

        // Fade image
        $('.item img').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, animateTime);
        })
        $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, animateTime);
        });
        $('.item').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).children('h3').css('display', 'block');
            $(this).children('h3').stop().animate({opacity:1}, animateTime);
        });
        $('.item').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).children('h3').css('display', 'none');
            $(this).children('h3').stop();
            $(this).children('h3').css('opacity', '0');
        });

        $("#loading").css('display', 'none'); // hide the loading GIF
        $(".outer_content_container").css('display', 'block');
        $(".outer_content_container").animate({opacity:1}, animateTime*4);
    });
</script>
```

Which leads me to think: could the fact that I am setting "display: none;" on the parent `div` containing the images be causing the browser to not load the images at all and proceed to call window.onload?

Comment: Setting the image "src" attribute will not cause the image data to be loaded immediately. You have to wait for a "load" event on the image object itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a race condition, the width and height of the image is not set until the image is loaded. Use the onload event to know when you can read the dimensions.

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.onload = function() {
        //do the processing here
    };
    imgObj.src = src;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Doesn't *seem* to be happening anymore. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
canvas.height = imgObj.height;gagein
```

What's gagin?

```
imgObj.src = src;
```

Before that line use the image load method and wrap the rest of your function in it.

```
imgObj.addEventListener("load", function() {
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height;gagein
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    canvasUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
}, false);
```